# How can i control filling data inside textfields if its precedors are empty

Tags: jquery

I have 5 Text Fields , how can i control user entering data in the text fields .

Means User can't enter data in textfield2 if TextField1 is empty

User can't enter data in textfield3 if TextField1 and TextField2 is empty

User can't enter data in textfield4 if TextField3 and TextField4 is empty

User can't enter data in textfield5 if TextField4 and TextField3 is empty

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">

<label for="name">T1 Category:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="t1cat" value=""  onkeypress="return nospecialCharacters(event)"   placeholder="T1" /> </br>

<label for="name">T2 Category:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="t2cat" value=""  onkeypress="return nospecialCharacters(event)"   placeholder="T2" /> </br>

<label for="name">T3 Category:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="t3cat" value="" onkeypress="return nospecialCharacters(event)"   placeholder="T3" /> </br>

<label for="name">T4 Category:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="t4cat" value="" onkeypress="return nospecialCharacters(event)"   placeholder="T4" /> </br>

<label for="name">T5 Category:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="t5cat" value="" onkeypress="return nospecialCharacters(event)"   placeholder="T5" /> </br>

<input type="button" class= "btn blue" value="Request For This Category" id="requestcatbtn"> </br>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2jfmzsdf/

I just need your sugegstions on how to complete this .(I dont want to trouble for exact answer )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't use 'br' elements but use CSS. 
Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jfmzsdf/1/)

HTML:

```
<ul data-role="fieldcontain">
  <li>
    <label for="name">T1 Category:</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputFields" name="name" id="t1cat" value="" placeholder="T1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="name">T2 Category:</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputFields" disabled="disabled" name="name" id="t2cat" value="" placeholder="T2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="name">T3 Category:</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputFields" disabled="disabled" name="name" id="t3cat" value="" placeholder="T3" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="name">T4 Category:</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputFields" disabled="disabled" name="name" id="t4cat" value="" placeholder="T4" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="name">T5 Category:</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputFields" disabled="disabled" name="name" id="t5cat" value="" placeholder="T5" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="button" class="btn blue" value="Request For This Category" id="requestcatbtn" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see I used a list for easier styling and a better overview. Also I gave every input a class and a disabled attribute (besides the first).

CSS:

```
li {
  display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.inputFields').blur(function () {
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    $(this).parent().next().find('input').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $(this).parent().next().find('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

Basically this js is checking if you focus/focusout an inputfield. if its value isn't empty it removes the disabled attribute from the next input and vice versa.

Hope this helps. You can adjust the logic inside the JS. This is only an example. If you want all previous elements to be filled you can simply add this to your js..

Answer (score 0):

How about using jQuery's `.prev()` method to find the immediately previous `<input />` element?

`.prev()` takes a filter ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)) so I think you could ask it not simply for the preceding element (which might be a `<label>`) but specifically for the preceding `<input />` element.

You could also achieve the same quite easily with native JavaScript, using `.previousSibling()` ([documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_previoussibling.asp)).

And once you have the previous `<input />` it would be fairly trivial to check that its value has a non-zero length.

Answer (score -2):

you solution can be : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5achkpd8/)

```js
$('input.txtBox').on('keyup', function(){
    var next = $(this).next('input.txtBox');
    if (next.length) {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) != '') next.removeAttr('disabled');
        else {
            var nextAll = $(this).nextAll('input.txtBox');
            nextAll.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            nextAll.val('');
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input  type="text" class="txtBox" required="required" placeholder="T1"/>
    <input  type="text" class="txtBox" disabled="disabled" placeholder="T2" />
    <input  type="text" class="txtBox" disabled="disabled" placeholder="T3" />
    <input  type="text" class="txtBox" disabled="disabled" placeholder="T4" />
    <input  type="text" class="txtBox" disabled="disabled" placeholder="T5" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```